# How to use Compile with NDSolve function for large no of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, compile

Matrix `M[t]` and and Hamiltonian of same order `L^n x L^n`.

```
L=3; n=3;tmax = 2;
Rho[t_] = Table[M[i,j][t], {i,L^n}, {j,L^n}]; //Timing

Rho0=ParallelTable[M[i,j][0],{i,L^n},{j,L^n}];
Hop[t_, i_] =
Transpose[
  Table[If[i == j, 1, 1+Cos[t]], {i, {1}}, {j, L}]].Table[If[i == j, 1, 1+Sin[t]^2], {i, {2}}, {j, L}];

I1[i_Integer] := I1[i]=IdentityMatrix[L^(i-1)];
I2[i_Integer] := I2[i]=IdentityMatrix[L^(n-i)];

H[t_] = Sum[FixedPoint[ArrayFlatten, I1[i] \[TensorProduct] Hop[t,i] 
\[TensorProduct]I2[i]],{i,n}];
```

I have made a code for large no. of time dependent differential equations with initial values. I want to compile this for using NDSolve. Here  is my code...

```
Rho1[t_] =
Table[
    D[Rho[t],t][[i,j]] == H[t][[i,j]],
    {i,L^n}, {j,L^n}]; // Timing

Fun[t_]= -I (#1.#2 - #2.#1)&[H[t],Rho[t]];
Eq0[i_,j_]:=If[i == 1 && j == 1,#==1.,#==0. ]&[Rho0[[i,j]]];
Eq0a=ParallelTable[Eq0[i,j],{i,L^n},{j,L^n}];
Eqsopwo[t_]=Join[Thread /@ Thread[D[Rho[t], t] == Fun[t]],Eq0a]//Flatten;
\[Rho]Termsop[t_]=Rho[t]//Flatten;

sol= NDSolve[Eqsopwo[t],Diagonal[Rho[t]],{t,0,tmax},DependentVariables->\[Rho]Termsop[t],MaxSteps->10^5,MaxStepFraction-> 1/50, Method-> {"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}]//Chop;
Plot[Evaluate[{Re[Diagonal[Rho[t]]]}/.sol],{t,0,tmax},PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: I remembered once I read some material (probably in somewhere inside the document) that said `NDSolve` will use `Compile` automatically…

Comment: Really? that means higher than double precision of workingprecision will be impossible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I won't use your specific set of equations, but will answer more generally. Suppose we have the following set of first order equations with forcing:

$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=A(t,\vec{x}(t))\vec{x}(t)+f(t)
$$

Suppose further that we have $A$ and $f$ already as Mathematica functions, for example, here is something random:

```
d = 2;
A[t_, x_] := {{-1, -1 Exp[-t]}, {1 + Cos[x[[2]]], -1}};
y[t_] := {Sin[t], 0};
```

Now we wish to use compiled versions of these functions in `NDSolve`, and we won't anywhere make an assumption that `d=2`. For each row of our equation vector we will need a separate compilation. We have to jump through some hoops because `Compile` has the `HoldAll` attribute, and we can also not let the expression `x[[n]]` evaluate since `x` is just a symbol with no parts.

```
expr = A[t, Table[x[n], {n, d}]].Table[x[n], {n, d}] + y[t];
Table[
    comp[n] = ReleaseHold[
         Hold[Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}}, inside]] //. 
         {inside -> expr[[n]], x[m_] :> x[[m]]}
    ];,
    {n, d}
];
```

At this point is is a good idea to make sure that the compilation actually worked, or if it is just calling the main evaluator in some trivial way. See an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions?lq=1) to learn about this.

Now `Compile` will be angry with us if we try to use `comp` directly as the RHS in `NDSolve` because we would be giving it symbolic inputs. As a work around, we define rhs which only evaluates when time is numeric:

```
rhs[n_, t_?NumericQ, x_]:=comp[n][t, x];
```

Now we can define our set of equations and initial conditions to be put into `NDSolve`:

```
eqns=Join[
    Table[
        x[n]'[t]==rhs[n,t,Table[x[m][t],{m,d}]],
        {n,d}
    ],
    Table[x[n][-1]==0,{n,d}]
];
```

And finally solve them:

```
fcns[t_] = Table[x[n][t], {n, d}] /. NDSolve[eqns, Table[x[n], {n, d}], {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[fcns[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Final Result Plot]

Comment: Very under-rated answer (from 6.5 years ago)!